# Relative urls in templateUrl with angular 4 and sails not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sails.js, angular2-routing

In my `app.component.ts` I have to define the `templateUrl` as this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'root-component',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

If I define it simply as `./app.component.html` it gives this error in console:
[image]

So basically this means that the app.component.html is accebile from http://localhost:1337/app/app.component.html because my `sailsroot/asset` folder structure is like this:

[image]

It would be very inconvenient to write templateUrls this way because for example in the `sidebar` component inside `asset/app/sidebar` folder the `templateUrl` would be written like: `./app/sidebar/sidebar.component.html`

I would like the relative urls in templateUrl to be resolved properly and I am not sure how to do that.

If it helps, I am following [this](http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html) tutorial. (all my tsconfig.json, package.json etc.. are same as given here).

Comment: you should be using `app/app.component.html`

Comment: @Aravind any reasons as to why I SHOULD be using it that way (even if I don't want to)?

Comment: which one you use `systemjs` or `webpack`

Comment: @Aravind systemjs

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add moduleId to the decorator like this :

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'root-component',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
```

However, according to angular.io change log, you should use relative path and you don't have to use moduleId, so I'm surprised your code doesn't work.

> All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" cookbook
>   deleted (2017-03-13)
>
> We added a new SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to our
>   recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts
>   "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute
>   paths" for you.
>
> We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That
>   is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. You no longer need to
>   write @Component({ moduleId: module.id }), nor should you.

Source : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html